# is there any way we can name our table as our local variable value (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

im tring this piece of code..
declareing a variable and than adding GETDATE() with casting so that table name is unique.. and than inserting all the data from the existing table to the new backuptbl i jux made..

```
    begin
    declare @st varchar(200);

    SET @st = 'tblNameBackup_'+CAST(getdate() as varchar(100));
    PRINT @st
    create table mytbl -- <<-- i wish to set my table name as @st
    (
    tID int,
    tName nchar(20)
    )
    select * into mytbl from thet-able-whose-backup-to-be-taken;
    end
```

actually i wish to backup my table at every transaction therefore i was trying this.. i know this is not the real situation (as i am also doing this for practice if we can do this or not) hope u understand my question thanx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make dynamic SQL, if I understand you correct, and execute that:

Something similar to this:

```
declare @st varchar(200);

    SET @st = 'tblNameBackup_'+CAST(getdate() as varchar(100));
    EXEC('create table ' + @st + '
    (
    tID int,
    tName nchar(20)
    )
    select * into mytbl from thet-able-whose-backup-to-be-taken;');
```

Be careful about injection possibilities, also instead of just EXEC you can wrap it in sp_executesql or similar. It's just to illustrate the method.